# Tagging rows in SQL database with usage status

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have some tables in PostgreSQL with details such as customer transactions, where we have a bunch of old data but new data is constantly coming in. It could look something like:

```
| id |   timestamp   | cost  | tax  |
| 0  | 1432807913984 | 20.10 | 3.20 |
...
```

A bunch of us *use* this data in specific ways, and we'd like to each keep track of which rows have been used for our own purposes.

An example could be, we decide to apply machine learning to the *transactions* table and to keep track of which rows have been *learned*, a column is made to indicate that it's been used for that purpose.

Then later on, a new task is required to use the *transactions* table for another post-processing task. Another column is made in transactions indicating if it's been used or not.

Is there any convention to use for these kinds of scenarios?

Comment: do you need one new column to show who used the data or column to show if it has been used at all?

Comment: You could use a `hstore` column for that.

Comment: We need a column to indicate which _applications_ the data has been used for, keeping in mind that we might add additional applications in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about conventions but certainly you can use array data type by adding new column:

```
alter table table_name add column markers text[];
```

To mark record as processed you'd like to run:

```
update table_name set markers = coalesce(markers, array[]::text[]) || array['some_marker'] where ...;
```

This will add new marker to the existing ones.

To check whether record is marked with `some_marker` run:

```
select * from table_name where 'some_marker' = any(markers);
```

For more info about arrays in postgresql see:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/arrays.html and
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-array.html